# Is there something like "jump to" or "go to"?

Tags: objective-c, c

Here is my scenario:

```
if(something){
    if(something2){
        JUMP TO ELSE DIRECTLY WITHOUT EXECUTING ANYMORE CODE
    }
    [self doSomething];
}else{

}
```

Is there something like this in Objective-C? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to do it?

Comment: Why -6 ? You hate "goto" that much? LOL GOTO!

Comment: @DevFly, -6 (now -7) is rare as an outcome. Probably just means that people don't like the way you ask your question. Perhaps some input for you to think about it?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that else be for the first 'if' the line of code between the second if and the else looks valid to me. +1 to balance it out.

Comment: @emragins you are correct, I failed to notice the first `if`.  That happens to me a lot with inline braces, I'm so bad at reading code with inline braces...

Answer (score 4):

As Objective-C is a strict superset of C, you can use C's [`goto`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html#goto) keyword, but you [probably wouldn't want to](http://www.google.com/?q=goto+considered+harmful).

Answer (score 2):

A compound conditional would get you directly to the else-statement.

```
if(something && !something2)
{
    [self doSomething];
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but many people would frown on its use:

```
if(something){

if(something2){
    goto label;
}else{
    [self doSomething];
}

label:
```